# MYSQL PARTITIONS BY TIMESTAMP COLUMN

Tags: mysql, primary-key, partitioning, on-duplicate-key

I have table with partitions by **timestamp** column (milliseconds). Theoretically it is unlikely to coincide, but can make the case that 2 inserts try to made with the same timestamp. Obviously it would throw an error for being duplicated the **primary key**.

What possible solution can there be in this case?

Comment: Why are you using the timestamp as the primary key? The column for partitioning doesn't have to be the primary key, it doesn't even have to be unique.

Comment: Solutions for solving the duplicate key?  Try the [ON DUPLICATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) option that INSERT has

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for response. But according to the documentation the column might to be part of the primary key: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for response, may be a possible solution, but there is any more elegant alternative?

Comment: @SamYan: Yeas, instruct your users to NOT insert 2 records at the same millisecond?  Or add a sequence number, so you can increment that when nr 1 exists, Or (more serous now)  do not make that  index unique.

Comment: @Luuk The problem is that I can't control the inserts. We are talking about an online betting system, where every time players click, an insert is made, saving the exact time of the bet. Since the betting table can have millions of inserts in a matter of a month, my idea was to partition the table by month, thus preventing the entire table from being corrupted at some point, plus to retrieve betting reports, it would not be slow.

Comment: The most _elegant_ solution is not to use partitioning. Partitioning, _like every form of optimization,_ sacrifices elegance and simplicity. It optimizes for one type of query at the expense of other types of queries.

Comment: How does partitioning have anything to do with preventing corruption? I think this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for response. Possibly, and most likely, all of you know much more than I do about how to design a database. But I am looking for a solution to the problem I have described in my comment above. I had also thought to generate a table per month, and at the end of each month move the old information, but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: I thought that a table without partitions has more chance to get corrupted at some point if we are talking about containing many millions of records (10 million) each month. And I thought that the solution to prevent the possible problem was to use partitions.

Comment: When using the InnoDB storage engine, the most common cause of corruption is physical flaws in the storage, which is just as likely to affect any partition of your table, or a different table, or unused filesystem space. I've managed databases with InnoDB tables storing _billions_ of rows without corruption.

Comment: The MyISAM storage engine is a totally different story. I don't use MyISAM for the reason that it is more susceptible to corruption.

Comment: The partition column has to be *part* of the unique key. So you can use `PRIMARY KEY(id, timestamp)` where `id` is a unique ID. `timestamp` doesn't have to be unique by itself.

Comment: To advise on a unique key, please show us all the columns, preferrable as a tentative `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, including partitions.